# window.postMessage with headless mode on nightwatch

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

```
browser.pause(1000).execute(() => {
  window.postMessage({ type: 'LEMON_EDITOR_ACTION' }, '*')
})
```

I can't execute this code with headless mode on Nightwatch.js
I even try with executeAsync, Same problem

Comment: The `window.postMessage()` method relies on a visible window to work properly, it may not work as expected in headless mode I can guess.

Comment: did you try with `--headless=new` ?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii it works. thanks. but i have a new problem, an ElementClickInterceptedError occurs when i try this

Comment: @HichamMalki With only executing the code you provided here?

Comment: I solved the problem with this:    beforeEach(async () => {
        browser.setWindowSize(1680, 1280)
    })